# Drawing a line in Python

Tags: python, line, draw

I came across the following Python script:

```
x = x + 20  
y = 300 - int(i) 
draw_img.line((x,300) + (x,y), width=10, fill=(255,0,0,255))
```

The part which I couldn't understand is `(x,300) + (x,y)`. What does using `+` here mean?

Thanks.

Comment: concatenate tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds the `(x, 300)` tuple with the `(x, y)` tuple, resulting in `(x, 300, x, y)`.

Comment: In particular it concatenates them, as opposed to to something like a component sum which would be (x + x, 300 + y)....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For (x, 300, x, y), do we read it as drawing a line from (x,300) to (x,y)?

Comment: That completely depends on what the API accepts as arguments, but that would seem a safe guess to me.

Comment: @Simplicty:  Expanding on both Dair's and Ignacio's comments...  _This_ use of `+` between tuples is the same as the more familiar concatenating ("adding") of two lists:  `[x] + [y]`, producing `[x, y]`.  It feels really awkward here, because when graphing a line, you expect something that looks like `(x, y)` to be a _vector_.  Adding two vectors would produce a 2-element component sum, while "looks-like-adding" two Python 2-tuples produces a 4-tuple, which is why this use is so confusing.

Comment: My _guess_ is that the parameter was written like that to indicate that that `(x,300)` and `(x,y)` are the endpoints of the desired line segment. But I agree that this is a little confusing, and it would be nicer if `draw_img.line` accepted a tuple of tuples for the endpoints argument.